# EDC Integration Thunderbird - timeout

Tags: gnome, thunderbird, address-book

At a certain time after starting Thunderbird i get this message:

```
There was a problem opening the address book ...
```

with the additional information that a timeout occured.

I am running Gnome Shell 3.8 on Raring.

Any ideas where i can find more information about this error or how to fix this? I have not found any logged information according this error on my system yet.

Comment: Hi. Could you please be specific about the error. Is it throwing a message as ': There was a problem opening the address book "Ubuntu One" - the message returned was: Cannot open book: Cannot process, book backend is opening'

Comment: Hi. This is the whole error message `There was a problem opening the address book "Kontakte" - the message returned was: Zeitüberschreitung wurde erreicht`